# Remove bibtex entries using older bibtex files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a master .bib file (call it `master.bib`) holding >2500 entries. I've changed research directions since it was first created, and I would like to remove the older entries from my master file using a file from 2010 called `old.bib`.

In essence this is something like the set difference of `master.bib` - `old.bib`.

One way to do this might be to add `old.bib` to `master.bib` and then use a tool with duplicate detection to remove **both** duplicates.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with `bibtool`?

Aside: foolishly I somehow lost the 'date added' fields in moving around between reference managers.

Comment: Which reference manager do you use at present?

Comment: `grep` for the keys, then `gawk` (or even `sed`) to delete them from a copy of the file.

Comment: I currently use BibDesk.

Comment: no, the grep approach seems best.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been using BibDesk the entire time, you can avoid messing with other programs like BibTool altogether.

BibDesk, by default, includes a `Date-Added` field for every publication.  You could just order the entire library by that field, and then select and delete the old publications.

Here's a quick step by step. I'll assume you already have launched BibDesk and loaded your `master.bib`.

1. Click "View" in the menu bar at the very top of the screen. Highlight "Columns" and click "Add Other".
2. Type `Date-Added` and then click "Add".
3. This adds a new column header in your interface. If you click that column header, it will order your publications chronologically. (Depending on your set-up, you may need to scroll to the right to see the new column.)
4. Select the old ones and delete away!

Comment: As mentioned, I managed to lose those fields, but this definitely is a good tip.